# Android : How do I update my textView in a Fragment

Tags: android, dynamic, android-fragments, textview

I am trying to use fragments to build my first proper Android App.
I have a main xml. which consists of two vertical fragments, the top fragments consists of just two TextViews.  The first of these contains static text and the second contains a value which I will eventually be getting dynamically from SQL.

If i put this is my MainActivity.java then it happily updates the value of the TextView in my first Fragment:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set the Text to try this out
    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.viewItem);
    t.setText("Text to Display");
}
```

I have two fragment XMLs and a java to support each so I want to put the setting of this field into the Java that supports the fragment rather than the java that is for the MainActivity.

When I put it in the fragment it looks like this:-

```
    public class FragmentMainTop extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    // -- inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentmt, container,false);

    // Set the Text to try this out
    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.viewItem);
    t.setText("Text to Display");
}
```

But if I do this I get an error on the TextView line:

"The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type FragmentMainTop"

So why does it not know this method?  I have ctl/shift/o so I know I have all the right imports.
I don't want to end up putting all my code in the MainActivity because if I want to then use the Fragment in another activity I will have to repeat all the code.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to assign the inflated fragment layout to a variable so that you can access its `findViewById()` method. Then you return it once you're done updating your widgets.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    // -- inflate the layout for this fragment
    View myInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentmt, container,false);

    // Set the Text to try this out
    TextView t = (TextView) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.viewItem);
    t.setText("Text to Display");

    return myInflatedView;
}
```

Normally, when you call `findViewById()` within an `Activity`, you're invoking `Activity.findViewById()`. Trying the same call within your `Fragment` class will fail because there is no such `Fragment.findViewById()` method. So, you must use `View.findViewById()` with your inflated view to obtain references to your widgets.

Comment: The references are sucessfully returned even when i do findViewByID on the Activity returned by fragment.getActivity(). But updating the views dynamically still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert but I would say that return statement within a method returns something and the next lines after this statement are unreachable :O

So try to change the order! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code from my activity to update a textview added in xml  tag. The textview are class level objects. Heres some code:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentRegister"
    android:name="com.proshore.loveis.RegisterFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view1" />
```

Heres the fragment code just showing the class level variable.

```
public class RegisterFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

TextView textViewDOB, textViewLanguage;

public RegisterFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//eluded methods here
}
}
```

Now the activity from where I update my fragment:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends FragmentActivity {
Button buttonEnter;
RegisterFragment fragmentRegister;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    buttonEnter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonEnter);
    fragmentRegister = (RegisterFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentRegister);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    buttonEnter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("dontknowitwillowrk", fragmentRegister.textViewLanguage
                    .getText().toString());
            fragmentRegister.textViewLanguage.setText("hello mister how do you do");


        }
    });
}
}
```

Note: not sure if this is a good way.